# How complete is an Oracle11g IMPDP?

Tags: oracle11g, impdp

I was given the task of upgrading to a new Oracle Database Server (11gR2).  The former DBA gave these instructions:

Use Embarcadero to export Roles from Old and execute SQL on New Server

Use Embarcadero to export Tablespaces from Old and Execute SQL on New

Use Embarcadero to export Users from Old and Execute SQL on New

Use expdp/impdp to copy the schemas only out of the full dmp file

My question is "Couldn't I just use the full export to do everything at once?"  The only thing I'm not 100% sure of is whether it will put all the tablespaces back to the same locations.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a full export (i.e. you specified FULL=Y), it should contain the `CREATE TABLESPACE` commands that would recreate the tablespaces on the destination server with the same data files in the same directory structure as the source database.  I'm not sure why the former DBA prefers to go through multiple steps rather than simply using impdp-- have you asked him or her why they don't simply use impdp?

Comment: I'm really not sure.  He's been here a long time (and is still in another area of the company).  I am a relatively recent convert from SQL Server to Oracle and really want to ensure that I don't do anything to jeopardize business continuity.  Thanks.

Comment: It will create tablespaces, but in the same locations as before. Impdp actually has an option to specify the tablespace to import: "TABLESPACES Identifies a list of tablespaces to import."